# Quick clarification of what Feyman meant here, talking about symmetry in physical law under reflection

Tags: symmetry, vectors

When Feynman says "Now if the law of reflection symmetry is right in physics, then it must be true that the equations must be so designed that if we change the sign of each axial vector and each cross-product of vectors, which would be what corresponds to reflection, nothing will happen." He is talking about reflecting the system (or 'experiment' or whatever you want to call it) **and** using a reflected coordinate system, right?

To put it another way:

When a physical system is reflected, the polar vectors that are a part of that system reflect to match this change, while the axial vectors do not, as a result the polar vectors' signs change in the original coordinate system while the axial vectors' signs remain the same. It is only when you then use a reflected coordinate system that you get the situation Feynman describes - polar vectors without a sign change (this is implied, not explicitly stated) and axial vectors with a sign change, right?